# Как найти локацию по координатам в файле geoJSON?

Tags: javascript, geojson, геокодирование

Используется язык JS.

Есть координаты типа:
Lat: 55.807066
Lng: 37.458454

и [файл](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=26b97fc75b414b5ca7c38a7039de07de) формата geoJSON который хранит в себе районы города

Как получить данные по координатам опираясь на этот файл? Какие инструменты или библиотеки можно использовать?

Comment: какие данные Вам необходимо получить по координатам?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ хотя бы название самого района, в котором находится точка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением было реализовано с помощью библиотеки [geojson-lookup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-lookup).

```js
import geoIndex from 'geojson-lookup';
import geoJSON from '@/api/mo.json'; // файл с районами города

const geo = geoIndex.buildIndex(["NAME"],geoJSON); // индексирование файла формата GeoJson
const geoQuery = new geoIndex.Queries(); // конструктор запроса

const moscowRegion = geoQuery.getByPoint(lat, lng); // получаем данные района, в котором находится точка

const nameMoscowRegion = moscowRegion[0].properties.NAME; // получаем имя региона
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много.Смотря что вы хотите.

Если отображать на карте эти данные то подойдут: Leaflet, Mapbox Gl JS, OpenLayers. Это всё JS.

Если нужно отправлять запрос к данным в виде координат [lat,long] и получать название района, то это задача обратного геокодирования.
 Решений тоже масса, в зависимости от объёмов данных и архитектуры системы. Идеально залить в БД, описать геокодирование в виде API доступа к данным. Другой вариант написать свои инструменты геокодирования на backend и там же хранить GeoJson.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая библиотека [`turf.js`](https://turfjs.org/) при помощи нее можно это сделать примерно так:

```js
function check() {
  let pt = turf.point([+lon.value, +lat.value]);
  let feature = geoJson.features.find(feature => pointInFeature(pt, feature));
  result.textContent = feature ? feature.properties.NAME : 'not found';
}

function pointInFeature(pt, feature) {
  let pts = feature.geometry.coordinates;
  let multi = feature.geometry.type === "MultiPolygon";
  let poly = turf.polygon(multi ? pts[0] : pts);
  return turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt, poly);
}

loading.remove();
```

```html
<div id=loading>please wait</div>
<script src='https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.js'></script>
<script src='https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/yLBewyr.js'></script>
<input id="lon" value="37.15865" style="width:70px">
<input id="lat" value="55.40726" style="width:70px">
<button id=check onclick="check()">check</button><br>
<span id=result></span>
```